# Текстовые поля и их заголовки в две колонки

Tags: css, angularjs, input

Есть HTML-разметка с элементами `input` вложенными в `label`, менять её не могу (сгенерирована в angular directive). Как отформатировать её с помощью CSS в две колонки. В левой - надписи, в правой - текстовые поля. Надписи в левой колонке должны быть прижаты к правому краю. Пробовал так:

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

label > *:first-child {
  width: 8em;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Email <input name="email" type="email"></label>
  <label>Password <input name="password" type="text"></label>
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

**UPDATE**:
Выглядеть должно примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а можете показать как должно выглядеть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можете использовать `display:flex`

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 16em;
}

label > :first-child {
  width: 8em;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Email <input name="email" type="email"></label>
  <label>Password <input name="password" type="text"></label>
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

[Сайт с хорошим объяснением](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**UPD.** для случая выравнивания вправо

```css
label {

  display: flex;

  justify-content: flex-end;

  width: 16em;

}

label >:first-child {

  margin-left: 1em;

  width: 8em;

  background-color: #eee;

}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Email
    <input name="email" type="email">
  </label>
  <label>Password
    <input name="password" type="text">
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Ещё нужно, чтобы надписи были прижаты к правому краю. Дописал это в вопрос.

Comment: @Oceinic, и _Email_ и текст в инпуте? или только в инпуте?

Comment: Только надписи (левая колонка). Как на скриншоте

Comment: @Oceinic, обновил ответ

Comment: @Oceinic, и по ссылке из ответа обязательно почитайте, там хорошо расписано про _flex_